# Trying to accomplish a 'slideshow' effect loading multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm fielding a request that someone essentially wants one master page with their logo at the top, and the remainder of the page will load a series of pages (populated by a static array) and then repeat itself.

My intent is to have a page load in the 'content' div element, wait a period of time (I only listed 2 seconds for testing purposes), and then the next page loads. When it reaches the end of the array, I want the array to reset so that this is continuously loading.

I'm sure there are probably better ways to do this, but through my research this seemed the simplest.

Any help, or pointing me in another direction is all greatly appreciated.

**Editing for clarity:**
What I'm looking for is one master page, which just simply has a header at the top of the page. The rest of the page would be composed of a single div element (or iFrame if need be) and the content of said element would change after a determined amount of time, automatically, with no input. The element would initially load 'testdata.php' which would be composed of multiple database calls, after a determined amount of time, that div element would reload 'testdata1.php', which is composed of completely different database calls.

I hope this helps better describe what I am hoping to achieve.

What I have so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts_css/jquery.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: #E0E0E0; height: 150px; width: 100%; margins: 0 auto;"> 
        <img src="images/logo.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="height: 850px;"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var linkArray=[ "testdata.php",
                    "testdata1.php"];

    for (var i=0; i < linkArray.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){$("#content").load(linkArray[i])},2000);

        if (i === (linkArray.length-1))
            i = 0;
        }            
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't very helpful, and it doesn't directly address your problem, but you might want to try using jQuery (http://jquery.com/). You could have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Set timeout to 2 seconds
    var array = ['page1', 'page2'];

    document.write(array[1].href);
});
```

Or, you could use some server-side script like ruby, or PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use jQuery through the '.load' function and it has the desired results I'm looking for, but I can't get the content to change to the second element in the array

Comment: Oh. I didn't understand. I don't know. I'll try looking at some things.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up doing the trick for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts_css/jquery.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: #E0E0E0; height: 150px; width: 100%; margins: 0 auto;">
        <img src="images/logo.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="height: 850px;"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var linkArray=[ "testdata.php",
                    "testdata1.php"];

    var timeout = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    var arrayCount = linkArray.length; 

    changeContent(timeout, counter, arrayCount);        

    function changeContent(def_timeout, def_counter, def_arrayCount) {

        //setTimeout(function() {$("#content").load(linkArray[def_counter])}, def_timeout);
        $("#content").load(linkArray[def_counter]);

        def_counter++;

        if (def_counter >= def_arrayCount)
            def_counter = 0;

        def_timeout = def_timeout + 5000;

        setTimeout(function() {changeContent(def_timeout, def_counter, def_arrayCount)}, 5000);
        }        

</script>
```